# Why is it a bad idea to save dynamic data in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

My company has an application which stores one value programatically in web.config file. The web.config file is updated about once every five minutes.

James Curran posts that it is a bad idea to modify web.config programatically in this answer [Dynamically change connectionString in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441774/dynamically-change-connectionstring-in-web-config/3441832#3441832)  but he does not explain *why* it is a bad idea.

I'm looking for reasons to convince my boss to not store any dynamic data in the web.config file. Links to good articles would be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The application restarts every time you modify web.config, for starters.

Comment: this is really the only reason you need.

Comment: what i'm struggling with is, even if it didn't, why would this ever be good? why not just use another file, if you must store data in the filesystem for some reason?

Comment: The reason that web.config is used to store data is because .Net makes it very easy to do so.

Comment: I would go to your boss and suggest that in the time you have spent debating it so far, you could have written the two lines of code needed to read/write another file :)

Answer (score 4):

It is bad idea because every time you modify config file the web application will restart. Also, if you are using "web site" project it will also be compiled every time you modify config. So you will have performance and responsicness issues. You boss probably  don't want that:)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the application restarting, you have several security related values stored in your Web.config file. Your application shouldn't even have write permissions to that file.

Answer (score 0):

The main risk is to allow the files in the root folder or the *.config files to be writeable by the web server process. 
It would look Like a major security flaw.

What you could do is have a regular task modify the web.config file if the user owning this task is does not give write access to the web server.