# SQL query getting Server name in triggers when using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger set on SQL table for Audit Trail purpose.
Here is the trigger code.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_bowzer_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[Bowzer] 
For Update 
AS
    INSERT Table_Audit(TableName, Action, UserName, ComputerName) 
       SELECT  
          'bowzer', 'U', suser_sname(), host_name()
```

It works fine and shows the username and the computer (client) name in Desktop applications. but in ASP.NET applications, I use a common SQL login so that database operations can be performed using this login. I understand that SQL Server is getting server machine name because of this ID. However, I want to capture the client machine name whenever a database operation is performed.

What changes can be made to get client machine name??

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your connection string to specify the connectionstring property WSID (Workstation id) as below

```
string strconn = "data source=SQLSERVER;initial catalog = DBNAME ; uid=sa;pwd=password;  WSID=" + (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
```

and then you will get `HOST_NAME()` value as client machine name in your trigger

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: It should be noted that, on any reasonably busy website, this will explode the number of connections being used, since each user's connection string is different so they end up in separate connection pools.

Comment: shall i write remote_addr as it is? or change it to the server name?

Comment: my connection string is defined in web.config like this  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=mySERVER\SERVER108;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User ID=USERID;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: how do i change it please guide

Comment: You wont be able to do it in web.config, its not recommended either. check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441774/dynamically-change-connectionstring-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

You can set the client's IP address using T-SQL [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx), and retrieve this data in the trigger using the [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

This design is not really suitable for what you are trying to achieve. I'd consider adding updated by column in your database where you can store user id or machine name of a user who updated data.

This way you'll keep the trigger logic simple and avoid too many connections to your database that might degrade performance.